# How to persist an array in Vuex after mutations occur? (Just persisting against browser refreshing)

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, persistence, vuex

I am currently building a simple shopping cart and would like to know how to persist an array carrying cart data every time I perform the addProduct mutation seen below. Is the anyway of persisting this data not permanently but just to mitigate against browser refreshing? I know of vuex-persistedstate but how would I apply it in this case.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
import * as Cookies from 'js-cookie'
Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({

plugins: [
createPersistedState({
  getState: state.cartdata;
  setState: state.cartdata;
})
]

state: {
 cartdata: []
},

mutations: {
 deleteProduct: function(state, product){
  state.cartdata.splice(state.cartdata.indexOf(product), 1);
 },

addProduct: function(product){
      this.$store.state.cartdata.push({
        id: product.id,
        name: product.name,
        price: product.price,
        quant: 1
      })
}


},
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use nuxt-storage for nuxtjs project or basic javascript where windows is defined as in non ssr vue project.

```
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import Vuex from 'vuex'
    import nuxtStorage from 'nuxt-storage';
    Vue.use(Vuex);

    // Without Nuxt-Storage
    let cartdata = window.localStorage.getItem('cartdata');

    // With Nuxt-Storage
    let cartdata = nuxtStorage.localStorage.getData('cartdata');


    export const store = new Vuex.Store({

    state: {
     // Check if imformation is stored in local storage or set arrar to empty
     cartdata: cartdata ? JSON.parse(cartdata) : [],
     // cartdata: []
    },

    mutations: {
     // Using destructuring to add state and commit

     deleteProduct: function({commit, state}, product){
      state.cartdata.splice(state.cartdata.indexOf(product), 1);
      commit('saveCart');
     },


    addProduct: function({commit}, product){
          this.$store.state.cartdata.push({
            id: product.id,
            name: product.name,
            price: product.price,
            quant: 1
          })
     commit('saveCart');
    },

    saveCart(state) {
        // With Nuxt-Storage
        nuxtStorage.localStorage.setData('cartdata', JSON.stringify(state.cartdata));

        // Without Nuxt-Storage
        window.localStorage.setItem('cartdata', JSON.stringify(state.cartdata));

      }


    },
```

Note: That when using for nuxt, the structure for exporting mutations, action, getters and state are different and should be put into consideration.

If commit('saveCart'); doesn't work try this.commit('saveCart');
Try out the [blog post to see example code of a persisted cart](http://voerro.com/en/tutorials/r/simple-persistent-shopping-cart-implementation-with-vuejs-2-and-vuex-in-laravel-5/2)